# Unable to convert Oracle form application to APEX Application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using the Oracle Apex 5.1. I am doing application migration that is converting Oracle Forms to APEX application.But in Application Migration, I could see Create application button Option.

What is the reason for not showing the button and How to fix the problem?

Comment: Since APEX 5.1, Oracle have removed the feature that generating the application directly from a migration project. https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMRN/toc.htm#HTMRN-GUID-8F584DDA-46F4-4382-BDE9-DB7DD0BAC18E